# Append with jquery to particular id & class

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I cant seem to append to a particular id & class. I want HEllow world to be Appened to only 1st

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
var id =94;
    $("#'id',.m").append(" <b>Hello world!</b>");
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="94" class="postitem m" >This is a paragraph.</p>
<p id="94" >This is another paragraph.</p>
<button>Insert content at the end of each p element</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Two problems: 1. `id` values ***must*** be unique on the page. 2. Note that your `id` values are [invalid for CSS](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier). `id` values for use with CSS **must** start with a letter. Since jQuery uses CSS selectors for finding elements, I'd strongly recommend using valid ones. (Those IDs are also invalid for [HTML4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name), but [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-id-attribute) allows them. Just not CSS.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder is that true even with HTML5, which does allow numeric IDs ?

Comment: @Alnitak: Yes. The HTML5 spec defines what's valid in HTML5, not what's valid in CSS. If you try to use an all-numeric `id` value with, say, `querySelectorAll` and you're not in quirks mode, you'll get a selector exception.

Comment: don't use the same ID on more than one element.  It's against the DOM rules, and causes exactly the problem you're having.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks - worth knowing.  I knew HTML5 allowed it but it hadn't occurred to me that they'd still be invalid in CSS.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier, for future reference

Comment: @Alnitak: Yes, I linked that in my comment above (blasted SO and not underlining links like God intended). In fact, I linked all three definitions (CSS, HTML4, and HTML5).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ah, I think you added those links after I did.

Comment: @Alnitak: Not the CSS one. I did edit in the comment about HTML about 30 seconds after posting the original.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two problems:

1. `id` values ***must*** be unique on the page. You're using the same `id` for two different elements.
2. Your `id` values are [invalid for CSS](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier). `id` values for use with CSS **must** start with a letter. Since jQuery uses CSS selectors for finding elements, I'd strongly recommend using valid ones. (Those IDs are also invalid for [HTML4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name), but [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-id-attribute) allows them. Just not CSS.)

If you correct both of those problems, you'll be fine. Note that if you have unique `id`s, you don't need the "m" class anymore unless you were using it for something else.

```
<html>
<head>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    var id = 'x94';
    $("#" + id).append(" <b>Hello world!</b>");
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="x94" class="postitem m" >This is a paragraph.</p>
<p id="x95" >This is another paragraph.</p>
<button>Insert content at the end of each p element</button>
</body>
</html>
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/omunud) | [source](http://jsbin.com/omunud/edit)

---

Separately: I **strongly** recommend adding a doctype to that HTML. Without one, you're in quirks mode, and jQuery doesn't support quirks mode (various calculations will be wrong).

Comment: +1 Thanks for pointing out the issue with my answer; mistakenly thought there was a hierarchy :)

Answer (score 2):

[Then it must be like this](http://jsfiddle.net/NvMAh/)

```
$('#'+id+'.m').append('<b>Hello world!</b>');
```

which is `$('#94.m')` with no spaces to mean that both id and class must exist to match